# Video Orientation in ASP .NET web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

My web-api store video in mp4 format, send by mobile client app (IOS and Android).

I make a thumbnail of this video, and when client app ask for it i send thumbnail first, and then video. 
It is working almost perfect. Almost...

Thumbnail picture (.jpg) does not include orientation of video. So i need rotation of video to rotate thumbnail if required.

How to find orientation (rotation) of video?

[edited]
I just need to access mp4's Exif metadata Rotation property.
Any idea how i can read rotation property in c#?